# Logstash input twitter `Error::Forbidden`

Tags: elasticsearch, twitter, rubygems, logstash

I am running logstash 8.2.2 on Ubuntu 16,04 with the following command:

bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/twitter.conf

Here is the content of twitter.conf:

```
input {
 twitter {
 consumer_key => 'nmOC0'
 consumer_secret => 'TQajpe0PSLwCP4M'
 oauth_token => '380242506-P2P'
 oauth_token_secret => 'OLhqUoIjnLj'
 keywords => ["AWS","Qbox","Elasticsearch"]
 full_tweet => true
}
}

output {
stdout {
  codec => dots
} }
```

Here is the error:

*[WARN ][logstash.inputs.twitter  ] Twitter client error {:message=>"", :exception=>Twitter::Error::Forbidden, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:24:in `on_headers_complete'", "org/ruby_http_parser/RubyHttpParser.java:370:in` <<'",
"/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:19:in `<<'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:20:in` stream'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:119:in `request'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:38:in` filter'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-twitter-4.1.0/lib/logstash/inputs/twitter.rb:166:in `do_run'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-twitter-4.1.0/lib/logstash/inputs/twitter.rb:146:in` run'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:410:in `inputworker'", "/usr/share/logstash-8.2.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:401:in` block in start_input'"], :options=>nil}*